Changing Video Metadata: Major_Brand, Minor_Version, and Compatible_Brands
There is an original video file with the data:

I need to get the data at the exit:

More precisely, I need to change major_brand from mp42 to ISOM. minor_version from 0 to 512 and compatible_brands.
Can this be solved through FFmpeg or other options?

Are you trying to change the format of the video, or just rewrite/edit the metadata?

Also, what research have you done and what have you tried? A quick web search showed a few options. Have you tried any of these yet?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886516/ffmpeg-editing-metadata-major-brand

Try re-muxing: ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy output.mp4. Note that you didn't mention the type of the input file. Is it an MP4 file?

Take a look at this comment from Gyan.
